# Get opposite result of INNER JOIN

Tags: mariadb

There is Table **A** and **B**

```
item_serial_no (Table A)  | forbidden_item_serial_no (Table B)
--------------            | --------------
1                         | 1
2                         | 3
3                         | 5
4                         | 7
5
6
7
```

When I use SQL:

```
SELECT
A.item_serial_no
FROM
A
INNER JOIN B ON A.item_serial_no = B.forbidden_item_serial_no
```

I will get 1,3,5,7.

But I would like to get **negation** of it, so the result would be like:

```
result query
------------
2
4
6
```

I am not SQL ninja and I have spent prety much time to solve this, but no success.
Thanx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
A.item_serial_no
FROM
A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.item_serial_no = B.forbidden_item_serial_no
WHERE B.forbidden_item_serial_no IS NULL
```

Comment: Absolutely.... Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.item_serial_no FROM A
 OUTER JOIN B ON A.item_serial_no = B.forbidden_item_serial_no
 WHERE A.item_serial_no IS NULL OR B.forbidden_item_serial_no IS NULL
```

Comment: You gave me the the answer as the first. But I had to omit FULL clausule, because my mariadb version at least does not know FULL OUTER JOIN. So the correct answer is from Terje D. But yes, you helped me much...

Comment: Thanks for vote up but actually I now see that my answer is not correct. because it includes table B items that aren't in table A and vice versa. You just wanted A items that aren't on B!